# glm orientedAngle gives vastly different result when x changes sign

Tags: c++, rotation, glm-math

I have the following issue when using glm::orientedAngle from GLM_GTX_vector_angle.
I simply want the rotation around the Y axis. What I want to rotate is an object which initially is pointed towards the positive Z axis (e.g. along vector `(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`). The current direction of the object is defined by a constantly altered vector `dir` (normalized). The rotation is done with respect to `(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)`. So, all vectors in glm::rotatedAngle are constant, except dir. Here's what I've found:

Code:

```
glm::orientedAngle(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), dir, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f))
```

Result for different `dir`s:

```
dir: (-0.00960893,-0.15582,-0.987739)  -> rot: -171.018
dir: (-0.00342022,-0.155258,-0.987868) -> rot: -171.066
dir: (0.00282073,-0.154685,-0.98796)   -> rot: 171.1
dir: (0.00874247,-0.154136,-0.988011)  -> rot: 171.119
```

Notice the direction change when the sign of the x-coordinate in `dir`is changed. -171 and 171 is nowhere near the same angle (`-171 + 360 = 189`), so 18 degrees off or so. What's causing this? The `dir` vector only changes an increment of 0.005 or so and other increments of that size didn't influence the rotation degree that much. Any help is appreciated.

---

**Minimum compilable code representing the issue:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/vector_angle.hpp>

int main(void)
{
  std::cout << "Results: " << std::endl;
  std::cout << glm::orientedAngle(
    glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
    glm::normalize(glm::vec3(-0.000209185,0.32454,-0.945872)),
    glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
  ) << std::endl;

  std::cout << glm::orientedAngle(
    glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
    glm::normalize(glm::vec3(0.0214591,0.326289,-0.945026)),
    glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
  ) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That sounds about right actually. It's easiest to picture this in 2D and in images.

Let's assume I have a vector, say (9,1). We'll ignore the Z axis and assume it comes "out" of the screen, which gives us the following. I apologise for my bad drawings, I don't have a real plotter installed!

[image: Image 1]

So, the difference between (9,1) and (1,0) (i.e. the x axis) around the z axis is around 6 degrees. Now let's negate the sign on the x component:

[image: Image 2]

The vector has moved, of course, but this isn't a rotation of 180 degrees. Instead, the difference between (-9,1) and (1,0) around the z-axis is now -6 degrees (arctan(-9/1)), or 174 degrees from (1,0). The issue is that the angle of vectors (9,-1) and (-9,1) are identical, so you're going to have to apply some extra smartness to determine if you should subtract 180 degrees from the result of arctan.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The difference between you're example and mine is that your two vectors are really far apart. To apply my example to yours, imagine two vectors which point nearly straight up `(0.0002, 1.0)` and `(-0.0002, 1.0)`. They should both have an angle of approximately 90 degrees